# Sending a transaction does not work in NextJS production mode

Tags: error, solana-pay

i deployed my website built with NextJS on a dedicated node server served by Nginx.
When sending a transaction, executing Next in dev mode both locally and on the server everything works fine, but when i execute it in production mode i'm getting an unknown error on Phantom wallet and the following error with Solflare: "failed to fill whole buffer".

Production mode works only if executed locally

Any idea about what could cause this?
Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, signin message is working but sendtransaction is not, working on dev but not in prod